# Can we preview live cam output on Watch App that is paired with an iPhone App using Swift UI?

Tags: swiftui, avfoundation, video-capture, watchos, watchconnectivity

I am trying to show live cam preview on watch app also but didn't found a suitable solution. To show camera preview on iPhone, I am using AVfoundation. But also want to show live cam output on watch app. Don't is it possible or not. If possible then how?